# Change format of date

Tags: objective-c, ios, date-format

I got a `NSString *string = @"2012-10-24 23:00:00 +0000";`

And I want to convert that to a normal format `24 october 2012`

I use the following code. But it keeps crashing. Can anyone help me?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy MM dd HH:mm:SS zzz"];
NSDate *dateNS = [dateformat dateFromString:date];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy"];
date = [dateformat stringFromDate:dateNS];
[dateformat release]
```

Comment: What does the crash message say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It keeps crashing because it can't create the `NSDate` from the input date because the dateformat is incorrect. it missing the `-` between the date and the seconds are `ss` not `SS`.

Also you need a date formate with `MMMM` to get the months full name:

```
NSString *string = @"2012-10-24 23:00:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *dateNS = [dateformat dateFromString:string];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];
NSString *date = [dateformat stringFromDate:dateNS];
[dateformat release];
```